# How to plot on one graph two estimated distributions from discreet data using R

Tags: r

I had a problem where I am at the point where I need to have two plots on the same graph.

```
losses <- c(67,53,87,70,77,76,78,92,73,76)
density(losses)
plot(density(losses), main="Empirical density",
ylab="p",xlab = "Losses")

library(KernSmooth)

uniform_kern <- bkde(losses, kernel = "box", canonical = FALSE, bandwidth = 7, gridsize = 512L, truncate = TRUE)
plot(uniform_kern, main="Kernel smoothed using uniform(Box)",
ylab="p",xlab = "Losses")

normal_kern <- bkde(losses, kernel = "normal", canonical = FALSE, bandwidth = 7, gridsize = 512L, truncate = TRUE)
plot(normal_kern, main = "Kernel smoothed using nnormal(gaussian)",
     ylab = "p", xlab = "Losses")
```

The two plot are: uniform_kern, normal_kern.

I am looking to get something similar  to this:

[image]

I have tried something similar  to this:

```
plot(the first plot)

lines(the second one)
```

Which gives an error:

```
Error in plot.xy(xy.coords(x, y), type = type, ...) : plot.new has not been called yet
```

Hence  I thought about asking about the existence of a much simpler way of doing this.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
uniform_kern <- bkde(losses, kernel = "box", canonical = FALSE, bandwidth = 7, gridsize = 512L, truncate = TRUE)
plot(uniform_kern, main="Kernel smoothed using uniform(Box)",
     ylab="p",xlab = "Losses",type='l')

normal_kern <- bkde(losses, kernel = "normal", canonical = FALSE, bandwidth = 7, gridsize = 512L, truncate = TRUE)
points(normal_kern, main = "Kernel smoothed using nnormal(gaussian)",
     ylab = "p", xlab = "Losses",type='l',col="red")
```

[image]
For something nicer:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data.frame(x = c(0, 1)), aes(x = x)) +
  stat_function(fun = dnorm, args = list(0.2, 0.1),
                colour = "red") +
  stat_function(fun = dnorm, args = list(0.7, 0.05),
                colour = "blue") +
  scale_x_continuous(name = "Probability",
                     breaks = seq(0, 1, 0.2),
                     limits=c(0, 1)) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Frequency")
```

[image]